# What's the best jQuery method to look for and grab another class if one class does not exist?

Tags: jquery

I'm working up a jQuery code that pulls content from one page and displays it on another. What's the best route with jQuery to grab a class from another page, but if that class does not exist, it will look for another class?

Here is a stripped down version of what I have so far:

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
    $.get('/blog.html', function(data){ 
        $(data).find("img:nth-of-type(1)").appendTo(".post-image-1");
    });
 });
</script>
```

In other words, if this code can't find the first image on this page, have the code look for another class.

Thank you!

Comment: Code would be helpful. What have you tried? Clarify your question: what do you mean by "grab a class from another page?" Are you querying content from an already existing DOM object? `$('.classname')` will give you all elements with a given class, and an empty array if none exist.

Comment: Sorry, @J.Titus! I've added the code into my question.

Comment: In your sample code you aren't looking for a class, but the first child of an element(`img`). If this code didn't find an image, then it wouldn't find any images.

Comment: Right, so if it can't find any images, I want the code to then look for a class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. This code checks if jQuery found an image. If so, it appends the image to the post-image-1 element. If not, you can search for any other class.

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
       $.get('/blog.html', function(data){
           $data = $(data);
           $image = $data.find('img:nth-of-type(1)');

           if ($image.length > 0) {
               $image.appendTo('.post-image-1');
           }
           else {
               // Search for another class here and append it to post-image-1
               $data.find('.other-class').appendTo('.post-image-1');
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```